# Is there a way to test HERE Maps offline?

Tags: offline, here-maps

I am developing web apps that implement HERE Maps. I would like to ask if there is a way to test it out offline (ie. in localhost or offline development machine)?

Comment: You can using the SDK https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/use-cases.html you need the premium version to get the vector data for offline usage https://developer.here.com/native-apis

Comment: I am sorry for not clarifying my question before, but what I meant about apps are web applications.